# Why is the episode called "Shut up and Dance"?

Tags: title, black-mirror

The third episode of season 3 of Black Mirror is called "Shut up and Dance". Can anyone please explain why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My opinion is because the 'controller' is acting as a puppeteer of sorts. No matter what the people he/she says makes no difference. Its like the controller is saying shut up and do as I say. When I say give a guy a cake, you give the guy a cake. When I say dance, you dance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the person/people who are telling Kenny and the others what to do are somewhat like puppeteers. Whatever they tell them to do, they obey. If they tell them to shut up and dance, that's exactly what they will do.

Comment: Saying an opinion is not a good answer. If you have something to back up your assertions, then add them. You can modify and add them.